# R (ggplot) function to add an 'empty' row in an existing legend, split legend?

Tags: r, ggplot2, layout, legend

I'm currently working on a plot. It's all coming together, but i'm wondering about one thing... I tried googling this, but I couldn't found what I was looking for.

Right now, I've created a legend that I liked. With 'scale_color_manual' and 'scale_size_manual', I've created a combined legend that includes the thickness of the corresponding line and the color. I have put the code I used below.

```
scale_color_manual(name = "combined legend",
                     labels = c("Nederland totaal", "Noord-Holland", "Utrecht", "Noord-Brabant", "Zuid-Holland", "Gelderland", "Flevoland", "Overijssel", "Limburg", "Drenthe", "Zeeland", "Friesland", "Groningen"),
                     values=c("#000000", "#001EFF", "#2ECC71","#FF009D","#00FFCD",
                              "#FF8400", "#8514EB", "#EB1A14", "#FFE100", 
                              "#FF00AA", "#00AAFF", "#16A085", "#B903FC")) +   

scale_size_manual(name = "combined legend", 
                        labels = c("Nederland totaal", "Noord-Holland", "Utrecht", "Noord-Brabant", "Zuid-Holland", "Gelderland", "Flevoland", "Overijssel", "Limburg", "Drenthe", "Zeeland", "Friesland", "Groningen"),
                        values = c(1.75, 0.8, 0.8,0.8,0.8,0.8,0.8,0.8,0.8,0.8,0.8,0.8,0.8))
```

This is what the legend looks like right now

[image: This is what the legend looks like right now.]

My question is: Is it possible to create a little bit of space between the first 'legend' part (so "Nederland totaal" and the other lines?).

I want it to look more like this

[image: I want it to look more like this]

(I made this for clarification via word).

Is there a function to add some space between certain legend items? I hope somebody could help me :))

**More detailed:**

The dataset I'm working with, are the average yearly housing prices per Dutch province for 2005 until 2019. I created a ggplot, the current plot looks like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eVlr8.png) now. It is basically a ggplot with the year on the horizontal axis and the average housing price on the vertical axis. I have sorted the color by province, and added the black, thicker line that corresponds the total average of the netherlands (which I also put in the province vector). I used geom_line all of the legend items are factors. I hope this was clear enough, if not, let me know

Comment: hi, welcome to SO. Could you kindly share what steps you did to achieve the combined legend. Please also provide some sample data. Doesn't need to be the entire data, just enough to make the question reproducible (i.e, don't need to be all subgroups, and also not all observations)

Comment: Thank you for responding! I edited my post, I hope it is more clear now :)

Comment: Hi, sorry I wasn't very clear. Could you kindly post the full plot code (not only the scale_... calls..) And please kindly also provide the sample data for the plot.. For example, output parts of your data with `dput(head(your_data,20))` and post the output. This will help us help you!

Comment: It is a really dirty solution :) but you could just add `\n` at the end of **Nederland totaal**: `"Nederland totaal\n"`. It will add extra space below. Not sure right now about the behavior of the lines though

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option is to use **`stat_summary`**.

This will add another aesthetic to the graph, and thus another legend, far apart from the other one.

```
airquality %>%
  mutate(Month=factor(Month)) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x=Day, y=Temp, col=Month)) +
  geom_line() +
  stat_summary(aes(lwd="Nederland totaal"), fun=mean, geom="line", col="black") +
  theme_classic() +
  theme(legend.title = element_blank()) + 
  guides(lwd = guide_legend(order = 1))
```

[image]

But the benefit of this method is that you don't have to calculate the averages per year and manually add it to your Province variable.

Answer (score 2):

Could this be applied to your data?

```
library(tidyverse)

tib <- 
  tibble(x = 1:3,
         a = 1:3,
         b = 1.5:3.5,
         c = 2:4) %>% 
  pivot_longer(cols = a:c, names_to = "id", values_to = "val")


ggplot()+
  geom_line(data = filter(tib, id == "a"), aes(x, val, linetype = id))+
  geom_line(data = filter(tib, id != "a"), aes(x, val, colour = id))+
  labs(linetype = "legend", colour = NULL)
```

Gives you: [image]

Comment: I think it's a bit better readable if you try to avoid the pipe within the geom_calls. I.e., use the tibble as first argument for `filter`. In this case I'd probably even create two separate data frames as one of those seems to contain the total, which seems conceptually a bit different to me.+1

Comment: Also, just to pick on very very small thing :) I'd use `labs(color = NULL)` - this will result in nothing to be drawn, rather than an invisible but present 'something'

Comment: @Tjebo: Too true, much better that way, also edited